# Работа с значениями и ключём. Python

Tags: python

Нужно по ключам выводить выходной, праздничный выходной, сокращённый или рабочий день. Это всё содержится так -
`[{'2022-01-01': 'weekend', '2022-01-02': 'weekend', '2022-01-03': 'holiday weekend', '2022-01-04': 'preholiday', '2022-03-05': 'preholiday', '2022-03-10': 'workday', '2022-03-11': 'workday'}]`

Я создал переменную, которая определяет настоящее время. Дальше надо было проверять, какой сегодня день, и по нему выводить значение с либы. Например: сегодня 2022-01-01, это выходной.

Сделал я это примерно так:

```
date_actual: datetime.datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
date_format: str = date_actual.strftime("%Y/%m/%d  %H:%M:%S")

elems_to_remove: list = []

workday = 'Сегодня рабочий день'
holiday_weekend = 'Сегодня праздничный выходной'
preholiday = 'Сегодня сокращённый день'
weekend = 'Сегодня выходной'

# праздничные выходные
for elem in list(data):
    if data[elem] in ('workday'):
        data.pop(elem)

for item in list(data):
    if item == date_format:
        return holiday_weekend
    elif item == date_format:
        return preholiday
    elif item == date_format:
        return weekend
    else:
        return workday
```

Но что-то не получилось, при любом раскладе пишет, что сегодня рабочий день.
Как можно решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас дан список с одним словарем внутри, чтобы пробежаться по его ключам надо `for elem in list????(data):` заменить на `for elem in data[0]`, тогда в `elem` будут ключи словаря, т.е. даты, сравните её с "сегодняшней" датой и верните нужное значение `data[0][elem]`.

Comment: Почему-то не работает

Comment: date = [{'2022-01-01': 'weekend', '2022-01-02': 'weekend', 
                  '2022-01-03': 'holiday weekend', '2022-01-04': 
                   'preholiday', '2022-03-05': 'preholiday', '2022-03-10': 
                    'workday', '2022-03-11': 'workday'}]

    date_today = '2022-03-11'

      for elem in date[0]:
           if elem == date_today:
               print(date[0][elem])